# How to send ntp request?

Tags: solaris, ntp

I would like to get local time of server. Is there command/way to get time of server.
Operating system is solaris

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would like to request the time from a NTP server if you want to get the current local time set on your server.

To do it, simply use the `date` command.

EDIT: but if you still want to retrieve the time from a NTP server, you can use the `ntpdate` command followed by the NTP server's IP address.

Comment: Keeping your local server's time synchronized (with `ntp`) is critical unless your server operates in isolation from anything else and you don't care about accurate logging, file exchange, etc. NTP is too easy to install and too easy to maintain not to use it.  `ntpdate` is a one-time set-the-clock.  Local computer clocks are terrible time-keepers: they drift. `ntp` keeps time synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to find a suitable time server is to use the [NTP Public Pool](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers).  Configure three (3) or more time sources from an appropriate pool (i.e. one geographically close to you).

Answer (score 0):

googling around found this:

http://www.camelrichard.org/topics/Solaris/Configuring_NTP_in_Solaris_10

To configurate it

and this

http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Application_layer/NTP/configuring_a_solaris_ntp_server.shtml

to reset it.

```
svcs -a | grep ntp

svcadm restart ntp
```